# Mac App Store works like trying to open iTunes via browser

Tags: mac-appstore

Greets everyone.

I've updated to 10.6.6 but my Mac App Store doesn't behave well - see screen below:

[image: My weird Mac App Store window]
It seems to be constantly trying to open iTunes for some reason. BTW, I'd logged in iTunes with my Apple ID, but this didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to your home folder. (your user name under places on the left hand side)
2. click on Library
3. click on Preferences
4. delete "ByHost" which is a folder.
5. delete "com.apple.appstore.appstore.plist" which is a file.
6. delete "com.apple.storeagent.plist" which is also a file.
7. restart
8. empty trash
9. open Mac App Store and it should work.

If you're worried about deleting files then just make a copy somewhere else before you delete them.

From [discussions.apple.com](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12970880)

Comment: Great! You help me as always :)

Comment: Haha that's cool ;)