# How can I re-install Mac App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

I just deleted (via AppCleaner) my Mac App Store app (which I couldn't log into for 2 weeks) with the idea to re-get a fresh app via Software Update.

But Software Update doesn't download Mac App Store anymore.

How can I re-install Mac App Store on my Mac? Thank you.

Comment: Use your Time Machine backup to get it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a stand-alone Mac App Store updater. Your best bet is to reinstall Mac OS X 10.6.6, using the [combo update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1349). It's a 1.06 GB download, but it contains all the parts of prior updates (the 10.6.1, 10.6.2, 10.6.3, 10.6.4 and 10.6.5 updates) and should repair your current install.

Comment: BTW, that my erasing of app didn't help with signing in. But this answer did: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/mac-app-store-works-like-trying-to-open-itunes-via-browser

Comment: @Boris: Thanks for letting me know. I'd thought that you had a two-part problem, but I figured that it was best for future questioners if I just answered the actual question you asked.